# Find all polynomials : $ P(x^2-x)=xP(x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

Find all polynomials $P(x) \in\mathbb{R}[x]$ satisfying $$ P(x^2-x)=xP(x-1)$$

Please check my answer :

$P(0) =0$, so $0$ is root of $P(x)$, there exists $Q(x)$ such that $P(x)=xQ(x)$

then $(x^2-x)Q(x^2-x)=x(x-1)Q(x-1)$, so $Q(x^2-x)=Q(x-1)$ where $x \not= 0, 1$

Substitute $x=2$, we have $Q(2) = Q(1)$

Substitute $x=3$, we have $Q(6) = Q(2)$

Substitute $x=7$, we have $Q(42) = Q(6)$

Substitute $x=43$, we have $Q(43^2-43) = Q(42)$

Since there are infinitely many $x$ such that $Q(x) = Q(1)$ so $Q(x)$ is constant polynomial.

Therefore, $P(x)=cx$ where $c$ is constant.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. You could have argued about the degree of $P$ also. If $deg P = n$ then $2n = n+1$. So $P$ must be a linear polynomial. Together with the fact that $0$ is a root, we can get $P(x) = cx$

Comment: Looks good. You also could do, as the other commenter suggested, look at the degree when you got $Q(x^2-x) = Q(x-1)$, as well. You could also take the derivative there to get $(2x - 1)Q'(x(x-1)) = Q'(x-1)$, which should look pretty weird.

Comment: @ Prince Kumar, thank you. I forgot it :)

Comment: @user357980. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Interesting method, and correct. Except for one detail: You showed that the initial  premise implies $P(x)=cx$ but did you show that $P(x)=cx$ implies the premise?...... You can also note that  $deg(P)=n>0 \implies $ 
 $2n=deg (P(x^2-x))=deg (x P(x-1))=1+n \implies n=1, $ so $deg ( P)\leq 1$.

Comment: @ DanielWainfleet. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go also with canonical form of polynomial: $p(x) =a_nx^n+...$, where $a_n\ne 0$. So we have $$a_n(x^2-x)^n+...= xa_n(x-1)^n+...$$ so $a_nx^{2n}=a_nx^{n+1}$. Since $a_n\ne 0$ we have $n=1$ or $n=- \infty $. So $p(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b$. Pluging in to starting equation we have:

$$a(x^2-x)+b= x(a(x-1)+b)\Longrightarrow ax^2-ax+b = ax^2+(-a+b)x$$

So $p(x)=ax$ is solution for any $a$.

Comment: Thank you, john nobody.

Comment: It's very belated, but as written I think this argument is flawed and/or incomplete; IMHO it would read better if instead of 'so $a_nx^{2n}=a_nx^{n+1}$' you wrote something like 'the leading term of the LHS is $a_nx^{2n}$, and the leading term of the RHS is $a_nx^{n+1}$, so we must have $2n=n+1$', etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is fine but it can be made more precise in the same direction.

$$Q(x^2-x)=Q(x-1),x\neq0,1$$

Write this by substitution $y=x-1$ as

$$Q((y+1)y)=Q(y),y\neq0,-1$$

Now let us define the recursion

$$y_n=(y_{n-1}+1)y_{n-1},\ y_1=1$$

Obviously

$$y_n \gt y_{n-1}$$

$$Q(y_{n})=Q((y_{n-1}+1)y_{n-1})=Q(y_{n-1})=Q(1)$$

for any $n$, leading to your conclusion.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you.  Happy new year !